# Keys.onReleased event with Qt.Key_Back is fired only first time after I install my app

Tags: android, qt

I have the following `Keys.onReleased` event handler in my QML code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    ...
    Keys.onReleased:
    {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back)
        {
            event.accepted = true
            //event handling code
        }
    }
}
```

but it called at the following condition:

1. I started the app first time after I installed it.
2. Pressed `Back` button on the emulator.

if I restart the app and press `Back` button the application exits, but my handler is not called.

Is it a normal behavior? If yes, what is the logic behind this?

I tested this on **Android 5.1** x86 emulator and on **Android 10** x86 emulator with QT 5.14.2 and with [QT 5.15](https://developernote.com/2020/05/building-qt-5-15-0-for-android-on-windows/).

**EDIT1:**

And what is more strange, `Back` buttons starts to work if I create a StackView page in my app window with a code like

```
stack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("SomePage.qml"))
```